# How to install Oracle JDK 14 on my Rasberry Pi 4B?

Tags: pi-4, java, raspberry-pi-os

I'm trying to install jdk 14 on my raspbian pi 4b but all tutorials either show how to download open-jdk or how to download an old oracle jdk version.
I've already tried to install the .deb file without any tutorial (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html) but it does not work.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install /home/pi/Downloads/jdk-14.0.1_linux-x64_bin.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'jdk-14.0.1:amd64' instead of '/home/pi/Downloads/jdk-14.0.1_linux- 
x64_bin.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
jdk-14.0.1:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is it even possible to install orcale jdk 14 on raspbian?

Comment: raspberry pi is not amd64  ... it's an arm chip ... download (if possible) the arm version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it even possible to install orcale jdk 14 on raspbian?

The [versions on the oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html) currently all appear to be x86-64 (for version 14).  Oracle java is not open source, so no one else could compile it.

So no, there is no way to install it.

Answer (score 4):

Back in July 2019 Oracle Java 7 and 8 was replaced in Raspbian with OpenJDK 11 but as of now, v14 of OpenJDK was released to GA March 2020.

If you cannot find a binary suitable you may well be able to build this IF you live in the authorised list of countries and are not using it for tasks listed under the licence terms.

My understanding is that both toolkits are built to/under the Java Technology Certification Kit specification and using the Oracle version requires a commercial license from them.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @goldilocks and @andyroo, you shouldn't be looking at Oracle for suitable JDK for the Raspberry Pi. BellSoft has one with LibericaJDK! I have install scripts for the different versions in https://github.com/FDelporte/JavaOnRaspberryPi/tree/master/Chapter_04_Java/scripts

For JDK 14 on Raspbian OS (32 bit) it is:

```
cd /home/pi
wget http://download.bell-sw.com/java/14+36/bellsoft-jdk14+36-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt-full.deb
sudo apt-get install ./bellsoft-jdk14+36-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt-full.deb
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

---

Update 20200921

If you want to use Java 15 on Ubuntu 64-bit: more info on https://foojay.io/blog/azul-zulu-openjdk-15-on-raspberry-pi/